# How to install chef-server with management console and nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: ruby, nginx, chef-infra, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to integrate a chef-server in my current nginx webserver environment.

Unfortunately nginx redirects to `https://chef.example.com:4000/login` (which doesn't work) if I call `https://chef.example.com` instead of redirecting to `https://chef.example.com/login` (which would work).

My configs:

**/etc/opscode-manage/manage.rb:**

```
public_port 443
webapp.port 443
```

**/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb:**

```
server_name = "chef.example.com"
api_fqdn server_name
bookshelf['vip'] = server_name
nginx['url'] = "https://#{server_name}"
nginx['server_name'] = server_name
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/#{server_name}.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/#{server_name}.key"
nginx['non_ssl_port'] = 4001
nginx['ssl_port'] = 4000
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com/chef:**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name chef.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;  # enforce https
  port_in_redirect off;
}

server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl;
  server_name chef.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/chef.example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;

  location / {
    gzip off;

    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;

    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4000;
  }
}
```

Here's the request to `https://chef.example.com` via curl:

```
> curl -Sv --insecure https://chef.example.com 
* Rebuilt URL to: https://chef.example.com/
*   Trying 62.[...] ...
* Connected to proxy (62.[...] ) port 3128 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to chef.example.com:443
> CONNECT chef.example.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: chef.example.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* NPN, negotiated HTTP1.1
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Unknown (67):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; O=YouCorp; OU=Operations; CN=chef.example.com
*        start date: Dec 17 11:19:51 2015 GMT
*        expire date: Dec 14 11:19:51 2025 GMT
*        issuer: C=US; O=YouCorp; OU=Operations; CN=chef.example.com
*        SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: chef.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.4.7
< Date: Mon, 21 Dec 2015 08:33:09 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 302 Found
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631138519
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self' chrome-extension:; connect-src 'self' chrome-extension:; font-src 'self' themes.googleusercontent.com chrome-extension:; frame-src 'none' chrome-extension:; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com chrome-extension: data:; media-src 'none' chrome-extension:; object-src 'none' chrome-extension:; script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' chrome-extension:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com chrome-extension:; script-nonce 2ec8a63645785f329650e82150502b62;
< X-XSS-Protection: 1
< Location: https://chef.example.com:4000/login
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: chef-manage=01f350576b270bbfb72fa8f17c0ba28e; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< X-Request-Id: e89cbb4417b658e8fb857c786747fe1d
< X-Runtime: 0.018629
<
* Connection #0 to host proxy left intact
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://chef.example.com:4000/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>%
```

There aren't any advices in the chef documentation how to setup a reverse proxy with chef-server.

Any idea how to tune that config in order to stop nginx (or chef) to do that redirections to port 4000?

Comment: What you need is `proxy_redirect`, which you have turned off. See [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really work. You could rig it up eventually, but it takes a fairly complex chef server config to pull it off. Chef Server is an appliance, it expects to have control over the machine to at least some degree. The sticking point is usually getting it to work with the generated URLs for Bookshelf.

That said, `proxy_redirect` will likely fix the immediate issue.

Comment: I've tried with either `proxy_redirect default;` and `proxy_redirect https://chef.example.com:4000/ https://chef.example.com/;`, both below the `proxy_pass` directive. Without success (nothing changes, redirect still happens).

Comment: What specific behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Exactly the same as described in the question. I call `https://chef.example.com` in the browser  ans it redirects to `https://chef.example.com:4000/login`

Comment: Add a `curl -v https://chef.example.com/` output to the question. Guessing there is a strange interaction going on with the proxy headers because, as I said, this is unsupported and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Of course. I've added the curl output to the question. I'm somewhat suprised, that this actually isn't supported. IMHO this is a regular setup for a webapp. Comparable (and even more complext) software like GitLab for example can be integrated in an existing environment pretty easy - Why isn't that possible for the Chef Server?

Comment: Because Chef Server isn't a webapp, it is ~6 webapps working together in a deployable appliance.

Comment: Got it. However that makes the usage of chef pretty hard. I have no own machine to install chef on and I think the most users without virtualization cluster won't just setup a own server just for chef.

Comment: Hosted Chef is free for up to five nodes, or you can check out some of the local-mode/solo based workflows. Both are generally better options for very small deployments, as running your own Chef Server is a major time investment in dealing with stuff like backups, HA, monitoring, etc.